# Try Catch for displaying input error messages

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, error-handling, try-catch, output

Hey I am new to using Dictionary in VB.Net and was trying to figure out how to go about using a try catch to check the proper variable type is inputed as well not excepting empty entries. The hard part I am confused about is incorporating an error handling message for the user. I would it like to output in the catch each key and variable that is not correct.

For example

```
Dim dblTravel = New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
    dblTravel.Add("Travel_Days", CDbl(txtTravelDays.Text))
    dblTravel.Add("Private_Vehicle_Miles", CDbl(txtPrivateVehicleMiles.Text))
    dblTravel.Add("Lodging_Per_Night", CDbl(txtLodgingPerNight.Text))
    dblTravel.Add("Travel_Total", Nothing) 

Dim dblExpenses = New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
    dblExpenses.Add("Airfare", CDbl(txtAirfare.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Car_Rental_Fees", CDbl(txtCarRentalFees.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Parking_Fees", CDbl(txtParkingFees.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Taxi_Charges", CDbl(txtTaxiCharges.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Registration_Fees", CDbl(txtRegistationFees.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Meals", CDbl(txtMeals.Text))
```

These are my two Dictionary Variables with their own index keys. I would like to incorporate a try catch both together and for every keys value type that is not in the correct data type  or empty value I would like to output it in a error message for the user.

Example of Output

1. Travel Days must be a numeric value
2. Airfare must be a numeric value
3. Taxi Charges cannot be empty

These types of errors should be recorded and displayed in a error handling message for the user. Those in the Example Output is an example of the output display as well as the two errors I would like to check for.

Thank you in advance for taking a look, hope you can help.

Comment: use `Double.TryParse` on the numeric controls and `String.IsNullOrEmpty` on the text control.  Complain to the user when they are not right.  No need for a Try/Catch, it is simple data validation.

Comment: Any change you could give an example for each?

Comment: So far I'm coming up with this:  If (Double.TryParse(dblTravel.Item("Travel_Days")) Then

        End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Try/Catch` is a bit of overkill for basic data validation.  Use that when you cant foresee what might go wrong - you have already given the rules the user input should follow, so you know what to check for.

Assuming some button_ok Click event:

```
Sub ok_click(....)
   Dim travelDays As Integer     ' double is overkill too
   Dim AirFare as Decimal        ' Decimal is better than Double for Money       
   Dim TaxiFare as Decimal

   If Integer.TryParse(tbTravelDays.Text, travelDays) = False Then
      ' the contents of the control cannot be converted to a integer value.     
      ' complain to user; MessageBox.Show then
      Exit Sub
   Else
       ' the TryParse passed, so travelDays is a valid integer
       ' you might also want to check that it is not negative!
   End If

   If Decimal.TryParse(tbTaxi.Text, TaxiFare ) = False Then
      ' the contents of the control cannot be converted to a decimal value.     
      ' complain to user; MessageBox.Show then
      Exit Sub
   Else
       ' passes too
       ' your "not empty" rule probably means they have to enter a number,
   End If
```

If all goes well (the data validates) those variables will have the values they entered.  So next:

```
  ' procedure to recieve the values and add them
  AddValuesToDictionary(travelDays, AirFare, TaxiFare)
```

You will have to fiddle with things a little - your Dictionary is currently (string, Double), I'd convert that to Decimal, the only oddity is `TravelDays` which is likely an `Integer`.

You *do* know that your Dictionary will hold one (1) entry for any key (like "TravelDays")?  It will bomb if you are trying to collect values for several employees, each with their own travel costs.

Comment: Thank you so much, I definitely reconsider when to use the try-catch as well as practice the try parse. Thank you for explaining it.

Comment: never, ever trust a single thing a user enters.  They are as likely to enter "I like pie" for the `AirFare` as a valid value.

Comment: So the First parse check for either checks if it is correct data type and the else would be for if its empty?

Comment: no, `TryParse` returns T/F whether the string input (textBox) *can* be parsed to a numneric.  If so, `AirFare` or whatever variable you passed contains that value.  Even if true you may still need to test the value: e.g. is it > 0?  If false, then the user entered nonsense or it otherwise cannot be converted/parsed to a numeric.  There is no concept of "empty" for a numeric - that is limited to strings (text). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx